# Typescript inference of one property after the assertion of another property

Tags: typescript

I have an object where the type of one property is dependant on the type of another property. For example:

```js
// The item types
enum ItemType { APPLE, SANDWICH }

// Map of a given item type to it's options
type ItemTypeToOptionsMap = {
  [ItemType.APPLE]: { ripeness: string }
  [ItemType.SANDWICH: { filling: string }
}

// The item type in question
type Item<T extends ItemType>= {
  type: T
  options: ItemTypeToOptionsMap[T]
}
```

I have some typescript elsewhere that iterates over some items (could be any item), i.e. `Item<any>[]`, for example:

```js
items.forEach(i => {
  if (i.type === ItemType.APPLE)
    i.options // <-- Typescript doesn't infer "options" as ItemTypeToOptionsMap[ItemType.APPLE]!
})
```

The issue, as highlighted above, is that Typescript doesn't infer the type of `options` given the assertion on `type`. Instead, it will keep `options` as `{ ripeness: string } | { filling: string }` (from above example).

Am I missing something?

EDIT 1:

I am aware that something like the following function would work:

```js
const isAppleType = (
  item: Item<any>
): item is Item<ItemType.APPLE> => (
  item.type === ItemType.APPLE
)
```

But this has to be done for each member of the `ItemType` enum, so isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you want is that of a discriminated union, where `type` is the discriminant. You can construct such a union type by mapping:

```
type ItemUnion = {
    [K in ItemType]: { type: K, options: ItemTypeToOptionsMap[K] }
}[ItemType]
```

Then if you also want a generic type like `Item<T>`, you can do it by restricting the union:

```
type Item<T extends ItemType> = ItemUnion & { type: T }
```

With this, a type like `Item<ItemType>` can be narrowed by testing the discriminant as follows:

```
let items: Item<ItemType>[] = [];
items.forEach(i => {
  if (i.type === ItemType.APPLE)
    i.options // {ripeness: string}
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgLsCAVAngB2FA3lAggBXwBkBRAGigGVcA5AEQHUYBhACSgF8AoLgSxAQAnAGYBDAMaZ4iVBiQB7APJo4veSADOAWVFpsXKFADa05OmAA6AsRIBdAFzYog3hhDANGxxrguQAc04DY1NZS2p6JjYHJ2FeABt4-n9vX2Sg7i44c1gECABVEDUQKABefUNDIwBpKH5cmXMYnGyMR2qKeRVirwazOSVu9W1dGtsMkzyw2x5WqTyAHiQoYAAPBBAAEw0+sIA+Mr7C4qgAMic5x2XM+OA4Orze0wXQ8z2jcfKPgG4+R4thPJBCQJAALAAUvDKBywwV4wigkIsczKpXKrwwVkIpAAlMFDLwLF1VMMoAB6MnYFxuDy9Hx+fzcDh4oA)

Comment: I found some TS docs about discriminated unions, but couldn't find anything like this anywhere! Sometimes it feels like their docs really lack human-readable examples and common use cases... Thank you so much!